# opencv with netbeans c++ linker error

Tags: c++, opencv, netbeans, linker

I'm trying to run the following code which i found online to see if i've set up opencv correctly,

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

namedWindow("Output",1);

//initialize a 120X350 matrix of black pixels:
Mat output = Mat::zeros( 120, 350, CV_8UC3 );

//write text on the matrix:
putText(output,
        "Hello World :)",
        cvPoint(15,70),
        FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN,
        3,
        cvScalar(0,255,0),
        4);

//display the image:
imshow("Output", output);

//wait for the user to press any key:
waitKey(0);

return 0;

}
```

And I'm getting the following errors when i compile,

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
main.cpp:12:27: error: 'namedWindow' was not declared in this scope
main.cpp:15:5: error: 'Mat' was not declared in this scope
main.cpp:15:9: error: expected ';' before 'output'
main.cpp:18:13: error: 'output' was not declared in this scope
main.cpp:21:13: error: 'FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN' was not declared in this     scope
main.cpp:24:14: error: 'putText' was not declared in this scope
main.cpp:27:28: error: 'imshow' was not declared in this scope
main.cpp:30:14: error: 'waitKey' was not declared in this scope
nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk:66: recipe for target `build/Debug/MinGW-  Windows/main.o' failed
```

I've compiled opencv 3.0.0 on windows and I've added the following properties to my project,
Include directories - E:/software/opencv/build/include
Additional Library directories - E:/software/opencv/release/lib
And I've added all the libraries in E:/software/opencv/release/lib to linker libraries.

Comment: Have you added OpenCV to your Path environment variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might be easy fix.
Add:

```
 using namespace cv;
```

Above or below:

```
 using namespace std;
```